# How to find out if a string includes a word stored in a variable

Tags: ruby, string, cucumber

I am testing browser data via cucumber. I am looking through a list of links on  a page, to determine which link I should click.

So let's say I have a list of dessert links and I wanted to find the one for apple sauce. I call a method that goes through the links and finds the one that has apple sauce after I pass the name apple sauce to it.

The string "apple sauce" is stored in @dessert and since @dessert will change often, I need to know if there is a way to find out if say "apple sauce" is stored in the variable @dessert.

when I do @dessert.text.include? "#@dessert" i keep getting false. I need this to be true in order to make the decision to click it. When I evaluate @dessert by itself I have "apple sauce"...

How can I get rid of the quotes ( " ) so they are not evaluated? I think this is messing me up!

Comment: Why would `@dessert` include itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to test if a string has another string in it is to either use a regular expression, where you can describe patterns for "close enough" matches, or to search for a literal substring:

```
@dessert = "apple sauce;pears;walnuts"
@dessert.include?("apple sauce")
# => true
```

I'm not suer why your question has `"#@dessert"` since that evaluates to a string exactly like that. `"#{@dessert}"` is probably what you were intending, where `#{...}` inlines a string value, but that's redundant since you're only testing against a singular variable with no other data. `x` and `"#{x}"` evaluate to equivalent strings if `x` is a string to begin with.

Comment: Um, `@x = 11; "#@x"` gives you `"11"`. An irritating shortcut but a shortcut nonetheless.

Comment: If `@x` is `11`, then it's not a string, it's a Fixnum. I was saying in the specific case where it's already a string. You're right that `"#@x"` is just an ugly and less flexible way of saying `@x.to_s`. You don't see `"#@x"` used very often. `"#{@x}"` seems to be the preferred way of doing it, so the interpolation is clear.

Comment: Some of Ruby's Perlisms are useful, at least to me, but that particular form of interpolation is one I'd like to see go away. It's probably a cranky old-man thing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comparing @dessert, an object with @dessert.text, an attribute of that object. Also, you are using a form of string interpolation that I, along with others here, would recommend avoiding.

Try

```
@dessert.text.include? "#{@dessert.text}"
```

and see if it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where I went into a container and pulled all the links out to see click, be navigated to the page, and then assert that the page titles, url, and breadcrumbs all included the text within the link within the container.  You could just add an if statement that will evaluate whether a link has certain text, and if it does, click it.

From lib file

```
def pull_text_and_href_from_continent_link
    @continents.each do |continent|
        find(".continents li.#{continent}").hover
        page.should have_selector(".#{continent} .continent-wrapper", :visible => true)
        page.all(:css, '.continents .continent-wrapper a').each do |nav_link|
          @array.push(:text => nav_link.native.attribute("text"), :href => nav_link[:href])
        end
    end
end
```

From spec file (this is a suite not using cuke, but the code is still similar)

```
it "should have the right page title, url, and breadcrumbs" do
  @array.each do |info|
    if info[:text].include?('See all')
      pp "Skipping the see all link for this container"
    else
      visit_page_logged_out(info[:href])
      assert_correct_page_url info[:href]
      assert_country_breadcrumbs remove_specials(info[:text])
      assert_page_title info[:text]
    end
  end
```